# css animation timing and JS carrousel interval - slight lag

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, splidejs

i'm trying to make a slider where a dot grows and another one follows.
Actually, there is something weird, I set the `interval` option to 2000ms for the slider
and the css timing to 2000ms.

```css
div.bubble {
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 100px;
    animation: vars 2000ms infinite ease-in-out; //here the timing is the same as the interval
}
```

When the page is loaded, the animation and the slider seems to be synced, but as the animation goes on and on, there is a slight lag appearing in the slideshow. Either the animation is too fast, either the slideshow is too fast.

https://jsfiddle.net/pas14r8g/9/

https://i.imgur.com/nrGPWwY.mp4

Here is a fiddle for a better understanding of the situation.
So far I've tried 3 sliders (Swiper, Flickity, Splide) and they all seem to create the same issue.

**It's quite subbtle, you won't see the bug on the first 4 loops, but it will appear and get worse.**

What I've noticed is that the slider always seems to be lagging 3ms or 4ms. I've tried adjusting the value of the `interval` option, but nothing fits perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The `setInterval` function only makes a *request* to the `window` object to call the callback function every `x` milliseconds.

You are not guaranteed that it will happen at `x` milliseconds, only that it will happen *after* `x` milliseconds.

There is always the potential for it to take longer than `x` and can even be off by as much as 600 milliseconds.

You would need to implement a solution using `requestAnimationFrame`, which is called **60 times per second**. You would need to track a delta between frames or use an accumulator to trigger your action after `x` milliseconds.

If you watch the snippet below long enough you'll start to see the lag.

```js
function hi() {
  console.log("Hi");
}

function hello() {
  console.log("Hello");
}

let t = Date.now();

function update() {
  if ((Date.now() - t) > 1000) {
    hello();
    t = Date.now();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
setInterval(hi, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification here.
The tough part is yet to come haha.

Comment: Hey, I'm replying here, cause I've been trying to find a solution for the past hour now, and I can't seem to be able to figure this out. Could you lead me the way on the `requestAnimationFrame` could work with my issue? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The code I posted works. Just use the `update` function above instead of the `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks Dan, not sure I got this right though, some lag seems to be still there -

Comment: Can you post your updated code? I can see if you're missing anything.